# Why can't I create a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

```
mvn -version
```

[image: mvn -version]

```
mvn archetype:create \
> -DgroupId=com.tobilko \
> -DartifactId=site \
> -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

I'm going to create a project with Maven using a `maven-archetype-webapp` archetype. Why can't I do it? I've just started learning Maven so the error doesn't tells me anything:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-
plugin:2.3:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to 
parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype
plugin:2.3:create for parameter #: Abstract class or interface
'org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository' cannot be 
instantiated: org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository.
<init>() -> [Help 1]
```

I don't want to have any other archetypes or a default archetype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont use `create` use `generate` . Something like this

```
mvn archetype:generate 
 -DgroupId=com.tobilko 
 -DartifactId=site 
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Answer (score 4):

`archetype:create` is [deprecated](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-mojo.html)

instead use

```
archetype:generate
```

See this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/) for the reference since you have started learning maven